# SQL Server database configuration error in sails.js using mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2008, sails.js

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server data with my sails.js project and I've used [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to connect to the database.

I don't have any named instance, and I'm logging in using windows authentication, the code I've written so far in my `testController.js` is

```
/**
 * testController
 *
 * @module      :: Controller
 * @description :: A set of functions called `actions`.
 *
 *                 Actions contain code telling Sails how to respond to a certain type of request.
 *                 (i.e. do stuff, then send some JSON, show an HTML page, or redirect to another URL)
 *
 *                 You can configure the blueprint URLs which trigger these actions (`config/controllers.js`)
 *                 and/or override them with custom routes (`config/routes.js`)
 *
 *                 NOTE: The code you write here supports both HTTP and Socket.io automatically.
 *
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers
 */

module.exports = {


    /**
     * Action blueprints:
     *    `/new/index`
     *    `/new`
     */
    index: function(req, res) {


        var config = {
            // user: '(local)',
            // password: '',
            //server: 'localhost', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
            server: '192.168.0.109', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
            database: 'test',

            options: {
                //encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
                trustedConnection: true,
                // port: 1444

            }
        }

        var sql = require('mssql');
        var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error opening the connection!", err);
                return;
            }
            conn.queryRaw("SELECT TOP 10 FirstName, LastName FROM Person.Person", function(err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error running query!");
                    return;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log("FirstName: " + results.rows[i][0] + " LastName: " + results.rows[i][1]);
                }
            });
        });

    },

    _config: {}

};
```

But it's triggering the error

> Error opening the connection! { [ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.]
>   name: 'ConnectionError',
>   message: 'Login failed for user \'\'.',
>   code: 'ELOGIN' }

I'm really confused and don't know where to find its document with `windows authentication`, all I can find is `trustedConnection: true,`

Please guide me regarding this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am probably answering this late, but mssql usually has trouble using Windows Auth. Use Edge.js to make your connection instead.